# Unity5 Plane pivot point creating

Tags: c#, pivot, mesh, unity-game-engine, plane

I created a 50x50 planes with c# script. I used vertices, UV and triangles. And those planes making an area. So no problem there. But my Plane_0_0 which is the first one is positioning at the center. I need each plane pivoting to bottom-left. How can i pivoting bottom-left with script?

Comment: Give a few screens please, I'm unsure what do you exactly want

Comment: http://hizliresim.com/gog7pZ
I need no set pivot point center to bottom-left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I've got it. You want the bottom-left corner "tile" to be the center of the whole "tileset" / "map", so if and when you rotate "everything", that should be the center.
Okay, it's easy. What you need to do is, make that Plane_0_0 tile the parent of the rest of the tiles (set the `.Parent` property of all tiles you want to be part of your pivoting to the "pivot tile" GO).
Later on, you can change this. So if e.g. some other tile should be the pivot center, you can "reset parenting". BUT reparenting is an expensive routine.
**EDIT**
As (like I wrote above) reparenting is an expensive operation, I was thinking about alternatives and this is what I found I would use: create a `GameObject` (let's say another plane) without mesh renderer, collider, etc and pull it out to the size of the field (in editor). Make this the parent of all the tiles in the scene. Then, whenever you need to 'pivot' everything, you can go for parent-plane's [RotateAround](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html), marking the rotation center whereever you wish (e.g. "above" the bottom-left corner tile).

I would also modify the standard Unity `Plane` and remove `Mesh Collider` from it and replace it with a simple `Box Collider`, save as prefab and use that prefab as my tile to save some computing time (if planes' job is nothing else but to serve as a plateau).

Comment: I did parent my WorldController which is an empty gameobject (actually only script). And WorldController gameobject at the (0,0,0)

When i changed to (-0.5, 0, -0.5) its going OK but if i change fullscreen playing its moving again.

Comment: Yup, because all children move and rotate with the parent, and they do this around the parent's center (or RotateAround point)

Comment: still not working :/ what am i doing wrong. Can i just put in rect transform and pivoting bottom-left?

Comment: @YavuzYalçıntaş If your pivot center will never change, yes. In that case, un-parent tiles in editor, then move your empty WorldController GO to the place you want to be the pivot center, then re-parent the tiles under it again. But it would be better to make that RotateAround work

Comment: I just did change my raycast hitting vector.  x and z values + 0.5f
That works for me for now :D Thanks a lot for answers

Comment: @YavuzYalçıntaş Cheers. For rotation/pivot keep in mind the above, this is IMHO the best way doing such. Please upvote/accept if you liked the answer and it helped you to find the solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. But from what i think I understood, you're trying to make your planes rotate. For this, you can use Euler Angles :

```
gameObj.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(
    gameObj.transform.eulerAngles.x,
    gameObj.transform.eulerAngles.y,
    gameObj.transform.eulerAngles.z
); //Find the axis on which you want to rotate, and apply a value to it, for example :
   //gameObj.transform.eulerAngles.y + 150
```

Where gameObj is your plane object, of course.

Comment: If by pivot to the bottom-left, you mean that your plane should be facing the bottom left corner of the screen, yes, it can work :) the axis and angle to face bottom left should be transform.eulerAngles.y + 225, but not sure about it. Try to change the values and the affected axis until you get what you need :)

Comment: thanks for the answer. But i dont need plane rotate. Just creating some pivot point with scripting. Here it is my problem. http://hizliresim.com/gog7pZ